# How to Increase RAM cache/buffer on ubuntu 22.04 desktop

Tags: performance, ram, cache

i have 32GB Ram I noticed my Cache is usually around 5gb or less. The most of my ram is wasting. in my understanding RAM's Cache is to speed up system and performance.
so I was wondering are there anyway to make Ubuntu to use more Cache? so no unused RAM go waste. Thanks [This pic shows how much ram i have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8Asl.png)

Answer (score 0):

It takes a while for caches to "warm up" -- if there is no memory pressure, the system will keep a copy of every data block ever read or written.

If you have lots of "free" memory, there are two reasons: either your working set is smaller than memory, or something just needed this memory for something else than caches, and freed it afterwards. Both are perfectly normal scenarios where you can't optimize further.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Simon. yeah all i do is max open 3 broswer. ( mostly 2) and at times VM machine. so you're saying i cant optimize further.